# if this row is emty then it will showing another row

Tags: php, mysql, row

how can i do if this row is empty then it will showing another row

suppose name row is blank

```
echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
```

so if name row is blank then it will show `echo '<td>' . $row['companyname'] . '</td>';`  row

please help me how can i fix this
thanks

```
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td>' . $row['buildingname'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['area'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['city'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['flatno'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['mobileno'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['agreementdates'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['agreementdatee'] . '</td>';    
        echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if(empty( $row['name'])){
  $tbl = '<td>' . $row['companyname'] . '</td>';
}else{
   $tbl = '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
}
echo $tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this i think this is working.

```
echo '<td>' . empty($row['name']) ? $row['companyname'] : $row['name'] . '</td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo "<tr>";
 if(!empty($row['buildingname'])) {
    echo '<td>' . $row['buildingname'] . '</td>';
 }
 if(!empty($row['area'])) {
    echo '<td>' . $row['area'] . '</td>';
 }
 if(!empty($row['city'])) {
    echo '<td>' . $row['city'] . '</td>';
 }
 if(!empty($row['flatno'])) {
    echo '<td>' . $row['flatno'] . '</td>';
 }
 if(!empty($row['name'])) {
    echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
 }
 if(!empty($row['mobileno'])) {
    echo '<td>' . $row['mobileno'] . '</td>';
 }
 if(!empty($row['agreementdates'])) {
    echo '<td>' . $row['agreementdates'] . '</td>';
 }
echo "</tr>";
```